# GWT generate-with and replace-with mix

Tags: gwt, replacewith

I encounter a strange issue today, with the generate-with and replace-with options in my gwt.xml file. I explain :

First of all, I have two classes "A" and "B" and an interface named "I", with "B extends A implements I". I also have a "IGenerator" generator

In my gwt.xml, I have something like this :

```
<generate-with class = "IGenerator" >
  <when-type-assignable class = "I" />
</generate-with>

<replace-with class = "B">
 <when-type-is class = "A">
</replace-with>
```

The problems is that my object A should be a B_Generated object.
I have to say that the when B doesn't extend A, it works and when B doesn't implement I, it works to... But in this case, it doesn't work.

Hope you could help me for this stuff...

Thanks you all before.

-- MORE INFORMATION --

In my project :

A : PlaceManager
B : Project1_PlaceManager
C : Project2_PlaceManager
I : AnnotatedClass -- means that the class contains some annotations that must be replaced by code snippets --

My PlaceManager does all the work for managing places, activities and stuff like this.
B and C PlaceManager have their own Places that are declared by annotations like :

```
@Place
MyPlaceA placeA; // this part is replaced by a creation snippet

@Place
MyPlaceB placeB; // this part is replaced by a creation snippet
```

So the thing is that running one or another project, the PlaceManager must be replaced by the good one, and the new class must be generated to replace my snippets.

NB : This description is very simple and the projects much more complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no chaining of deferred-binding rules: the first rule that matches is used, and the result is not evaluated against the rules. That means you cannot say that `GWT.create(A.class)` would run your `IGenerator` that expects a class implementing `I`, that `A` doesn't implement.

You'd have to either create an `AFactory` (that would simply do a `new A()`  by default) that you could replace with a `BFactory` (that would do a `GWT.create(B.class)`, triggering your `IGenerator`) and change your code to use that indirection; or create a generator that can match `A` and call into your `IGenerator` with `B` as input (instead of the received `A`).

That said, I think you're (kind of) *abusing* deferred-binding, and should rather use some kind of dependency injection (that could bind a `GWT.create(B.class)` when an `A` is expected).

Comment: Merci Thomas. While waiting for an answer it's what I did, as I was doing before trying this. Thanks for tour answer. About your advice for dependency injection I used to use GIN/GUICE bu for the projection I work on, it wasn't enough and that's the IGenerator origin. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but from what I know and being using you choose either to use a generator or use replacement but not both for the same class. I do not really see the point.

Why generating a class for it to be replaced by another ?

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html

Comment: Hi, I think you understand my problem in the wrong way. May be I described it wrong...

In my app I have the following line A a = GWT.create(A.class). The replace with is applied on it and I recevice a B object. So I have something like A a = GWT.create(B.class); That's what I wanted first...

Now, I have my B class and this B class implements I. So, the generator should work on it. And I will have something like A a = GWT.create(B_IGenerated.class); which is I really need.

I'll edit my post because my description is too long... ;) But thxs!